# Dataflow. ValueProvider. How to create from several options?

Tags: apache-beam, dataflow, value-provider

I successfully use NestedValueProvider if I need to perform some transformations with input value before providing it into step.

But how should I act if I need to combine 2+ Value inputs?

In documentations it said:

```
Note: NestedValueProvider accepts only one value input. You can't use a NestedValueProvider to combine two different values.
```

Answer (score 0):

`NestedValueProvider` is used to take another `ValueProvider` and transform it using a function. It currently does not support combining values from two or more `ValueProviders`. Any constant values can be provided as a part of the function definition.