# GCS and Java- Concatenate dynamic bucket name and file name in TestIO

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-storage

I want to write a file to a GCS bucket. The bucket path and file name are dynamically provided in two different pipeline options. How can I concatenate those in TextIO to write the file to the GCS bucket.

I tried doing this but no luck.

```
o.apply("Test:",TextIO.write()
                .to(options.getBucktName().toString()+options.getOutName().toString()));
```

where getOutName = test.txt
and getBucktName = gs://bucket

Edit: Options are ValueProvider

Answer (score 2):

We have faced a similar situation in Dataflow Templates, and we have created [DualInputNestedValueProvider](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/main/v1/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/util/DualInputNestedValueProvider.java) to address this.

You can feed it with 2 ValueProviders (it could be RuntimeValueProvider and a StaticValueProvider, in your case), and a function to map them to a new ValueProvider.

Take a look [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/main/v1/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubSubToBigQuery.java#L334-L347) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

By "dynamically provided" do you mean those options are runtime `ValueProvider` instances? If so, I don't think it's possible to express what you want, since there's currently no hook for combining value providers (per [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67977956/dataflow-valueprovider-how-to-create-from-several-options)).

If these are not value providers, then the example you show should work fine (although missing a `/` between the bucket and path as written).

Can you share more about how the options are defined?

Comment: Yes ValueProvider