# How to concate Two ValueProvider and assign it to new ValueProvider?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I want to concatenate the value of two `ValueProvider<String>` and assign it to a new `ValueProvider<String>`
How I can achieve it?

```
ValueProvider<String> A; //if A = Nikhil;
ValueProvider<String> B; //if B = Suthar;
ValueProvider<String> C = A + B; //Then C = Nikhil Suthar;
```

Comment: Hi @Nikhil Suthar, did the below answer resolve your issue?

Comment: I am aware about get and that will not work, I want ValueProvider<Srting> not String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine different providers into one, see this as an example: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/main/v1/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/util/DualInputNestedValueProvider.java.

Comment: Thanks, I am also working with this and trying to understand the logic.

Answer (score 0):

The ValueProvider provides a get() method (see [Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/options/ValueProvider.html)). So you can do sth like this:

```
ValueProvider<String> a; 
ValueProvider<String> b; 
String c = a.get() + b.get();
```

Comment: I can not use get() first of all and secondly I don't want data as String Type.

Comment: @NikhilSuthar - Can you add a bit more detail on why you need the combined value as a ValueProvider<String>? I'm guessing that you need to pass it into a built-in transform that take a ValueProvider, but would be good to specify. Roland's solution would work in runtime contexts such as in the body of a DoFn.

Answer (score 0):

This question comes up from time to time (see [Dataflow. ValueProvider. How to create from several options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67977956/dataflow-valueprovider-how-to-create-from-several-options) for example) but there is not currently support for combining ValueProviders in the Beam Java SDK. `NestedValueProvider` is available for transforming a runtime parameter, but it doesn't support multiple inputs.

Comment: yes,  I had asked this question because of this limitation of NestedValueProvider. I am working on GCP Provided Method do DualNestedProvider, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look into using [flex templates](https://dataintegration.info/why-you-should-be-using-flex-templates-for-your-dataflow-deployments) instead, which avoid having to worry about ValueProviders at all.